# Wanderwort origins and the Indus Valley Civilization?

Tags: ancient-history, language, trade, indus-valley

I have noticed that there seem to be many words that have travelled the globe due to trade, such as the word orange or rice, which have plausible origins in proto-Dravidian. Meanwhile, it is hypothesized that the language (if it is a language, which some people argue against) recorded in the Indus script is a Dravidian one. All this makes me wonder if these numerous possibly-Dravidian Wanderworts are indicative of the Indus Valley Civilization's success in trade.

[This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Sanskrit_origin) of Wikipedia lists 7 English words with possible Dravidian origins, notably:

- **Orange**, through Old French orenge, Medieval Latin orenge and Italian arancia from Arabic نارنج naranj, via Persian نارنگ narang and Sanskrit नारङ्ग naranga-s meaning "an orange tree", derived from proto-Dravidian.
- **Rice**, via Old French ris and Italian riso from Latin oriza, which is from Greek ὄρυζα oryza, through an Indo-Iranian tongue finally from Sanskrit व्रीहिस् vrihi-s "rice", derived from proto-Dravidian.
- **Sugar**, through Old French sucre, Italian zucchero, Medieval Latin succarum, Arabic: سكر sukkar and Persian: شکر shakar ultimately from Sanskrit शर्करा sharkara which means "ground or candied sugar" (originally "grit" or "gravel"), from proto-Dravidian.

So, is it likely that the Dravidian language that these words came from is the language of the Indus Valley Civilization? Is this a poor, uninformed idea? or, alternatively, am I late to the party and this is already intuitively obvious to historians? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I believe this is more suited to our sister site: http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Really? I feel like this is much much more suited for a history kind of place and not at all an English one, especially because it's a question about these Wanderworts in general in languages all over the world, and why so many are theorized (by some) to have come from a Dravidian language, whereas nowadays we don't see Dravidian languages being that central to civilization; as opposed to being a simple etymology question about an English word.

Comment: I waited to see your response before voting to *Put on Hold*. The linguistics experts hang out at ELU rather than here. There is always a historical element to any linguistics question, so relevant experts will understand the historical context, and in this case I believe the linguistics expertise is much more relevant than the historical.

Comment: Fair enough--I'll try it out. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I have flagged a moderator to consider migrating it.  will look an answer over at ELU.

Comment: I've upvoted the question, historians learn from linguists, and linguists learn from historians. They are inseperable branch of studies.

Comment: It's not indications that they were *successful* in trade. It's just indications that the Dravidians probably for a long time was the source of the rice, sugar and oranges that was first traded westwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sad to say, probably not. Let's look at the reported itenerary of these words:

> Rice: via Old French ris and Italian riso from Latin oriza, which is
>   from Greek ὄρυζα oryza, through an Indo-Iranian tongue finally from
>   Sanskrit व्रीहिस् vrihi-s "rice", derived from proto-Dravidian.

So this word was first imported to Sanskrit (an Indo-Euorpean language descended likely from the language spoken by folks who destroyed the Indus Valley Civ), then to Greek, likely during the immediate time post-Alexander when those two languages would have been in contact. So no, unless you count having your territory overrun to be "trade", this wouldn't be one.

You see a similar pattern with your other two words:

> Orange  through Old French orenge, Medieval Latin orenge and Italian
>   arancia from Arabic نارنج naranj, via Persian نارنگ narang and
>   Sanskrit नारङ्ग naranga-s meaning "an orange tree", derived from
>   proto-Dravidian.
>
> Sugar  through Old French sucre, Italian zucchero, Medieval Latin
>   succarum, Arabic: سكر sukkar and Persian: شکر shakar ultimately from
>   Sanskrit शर्करा sharkara which means "ground or candied sugar"
>   (originally "grit" or "gravel"), from proto-Dravidian.

Both of these went into Sanskrit first, then into Persian, then to Arabic. The Sanskrit would indicate an Indo-European takeover of the words in the subcontinent. The Persian -> Arabic implies that the actual trade that moved these words west didn't happen until the Middle Ages. The Persians took over their namesake territory in the near east from the Greeks in the early middle ages. Arabic wasn't a particularly important (or well-traveled) language until about the 7th Century AD.

So it looks like in all cases the outside world only knows these terms thanks to the (Indo-European) Sanskrit speakers. Where trade outside the subcontinent is concerned, the trading parties appear to have been Greeks and Persians, trading with Sanskrit speakers.

Comment: The Medes and Persians were Iranian (from Aryan) people settled in modern Iran from the Bronze Age (2nd millennium BC): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medes and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_people

Comment: Sanskrit is not spoken but chanted, on the other hand Tamil is spoken.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia gives etymology of the word, search each word separately.
**Mango** originated from the Malayalam via Portuguese (also manga) during spice trade with Kerala in 1498.
**Rice**  Originated from Indo-Aryan (as in Sanskrit vrīhí-) and subsequently to Proto-Dravidian *wariñci according to Witzel and others.
**Orange** Originated from the Sanskrit word for "orange tree" (नारङ्ग nāraṅga), which is probably of Proto-Dravidian origin.
**Anaconda**  The word anaconda is derived from the name of a snake from Sri Lanka. However, the name commonly used in Brazil is **sucuri, sucuriju or sucuriuba**. Reference: *Wikipedia*.

Comment: It is far fetched to attribute Proto-Dravidian origins to Indus Valley Civilisation based on word etymology.

Comment: Copying something word for word is called quoting, not referencing.